# Unable to click '100' search results class and xpath - selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Unable to click the '100' button to show 100 results for the HTMl provided. I have tried the Xpath, the class, cssselector but there is something I'm clearly doing wrong.

HTML: ***https://pastebin.com/miyyVLP7***

Page URL: https://www.dlapiper.com/en/uk/people/#q=london&sort=relevancy

```
        WebElement hundredResults = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='peoplesearch']/div[3]/div[4]/div[9]/ul/li[4]/a"));

    hundredResults.click();
```

Comment: The pastebin is empty

Comment: hi mate, i can see it.. https://pastebin.com/miyyVLP7

Comment: Ok for some reason I can't see it.

Comment: if it helps another paste website - https://expandinggreenlanddog.htmlpasta.com/

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='coveo-results-column']/ul/li[4]/a"));` 

See if this work?

Comment: hey - no joy sadly

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='peoplesearch']/div[3]/div[4]/div[9]/ul/li[a")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Seems like there's another element in front of the button.

Comment: hi mate - no joy sadly.. i did the following
`WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='peoplesearch']/div[3]/div[4]/div[9]/ul/li[a"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",element);`